# Selecting children of parent, based on other child

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

Using HTMLAgilityPack I am trying to generate a list of clickable objects, using the function FindElementsByXPath, based on below structure.

```
<div class = "table-container">
    <div>  
            <strong>
                <a>Txt<a/>
            </strong>
    </div>
    <Table class="sc" style="display: None;">  
    </Table>
</div>
```

The problem however is that I only want to include the deepest-level a-tag if the table has the style-attribute set to "display: None;" (note that if the table is already expanded, the style attribute does not exist).

I am trying to generate an XPath expression that would help me achieve this. So far, I have made this:

```
//*[@class='table-container' and table[contains(@style,'display: None;')]]/div/strong/a
```

However, this is not working. I tried to search for the solution online and experimented with various settings, but no luck so far. I am new to XPath selectors and find myself stuck at this moment. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after returning from work and looking at it anew. Turns out if you hadn't clicked on the contained text in the a-tag, the table was simply not "there" as far as the XML was concerned. Only once you have clicked on it, it became visible in firebug with a distinguishing style being equal to either "display: None;" or being empty. For my application, I thus had to check if the table was present and, if not, click the a-tag. The definitive XPath was:

```
//*[@class='table-container' and not(Table)]/div/strong/a
```

Credit does have to go Ezra for pointing out the nuances of XPath!

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

The following query should work:

```
//*[@class='table-container' and Table[contains(@style,'display: None;')]]/div/strong/a
```

It's very close to what you had.

## Testing

I tested it on the following Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root> 
  <div class="table-container"> 
    <div> 
      <strong> 
        <a>Txt</a> 
      </strong> 
    </div>  
    <Table class="sc" style="display: None;"/> 
  </div>  
  <div class="table-container"> 
    <div> 
      <strong> 
        <a>Txt2</a> 
      </strong> 
    </div>  
    <Table class="sc"/> 
  </div> 
</root>
```

and it returns

```
<a>Txt</a>
```

## Notes

You query was basically correct. Note the following.

1. Xml parsers can be really finicky. Check the case of the items in the selectors. For example, `table` might not match, but `Table` might.
2. Xml parsers can be really fragile. Check that the markup that you're trying to parse is valid. In the posted snipped we had `<a>Txt<a/>` which caused my parser to barf. Once I changed it to `<a>Txt</a>` it was fine.
3. There are often many different ways to do the same thing. The most appropriate will depend heavily on the structure of your actual Xml. For example, `//div[Table[@style='display: None;']]//a` works fine on the test data, but might not work "in real life". For example, if the Xml you're actually using varied between `display:None` and `display: None` (with a space after the colon) that would cause another problem.

Comment: First of all, thank you VERY much for your elaborate answer. It's really handy for such a XPath noob as me. The answer however was actually something else. About the same order of ease.... but still different! :)

Comment: What I posted works. Care to share what your problem was?

Comment: Absolutely, check my post! I missed a pretty stupid little detail.... you absolutely had the right call on capitalisation though!

Comment: Glad I could help.